# iOS 10 Callkit does not show incoming call UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

I've just implemented CallKit into our VOIP app but I'm struggling with getting the incoming call UI to show up.

In my experiment I just created a simple method that should show the incoming call UI, see below:

```
CXProviderConfiguration * configuration = [[CXProviderConfiguration alloc] initWithLocalizedName:@"Bitcall"];
CXProvider *callkitProvider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration: configuration];
[callkitProvider setDelegate:self queue:nil];
CXCallUpdate *update = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
update.localizedCallerName = @"Ravadam Patel";
[callkitProvider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:[NSUUID UUID]  update:update completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Everything seems to be working fine and I actually get a `call received` print out with this code:

```
- (void)handleCall
{
  self.callCenter.callEventHandler = ^(CTCall *call){

    if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected])
    {
      //NSLog(@"call stopped");
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing])
    {
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected])
    {
      NSLog(@"Call ended");
    }
    else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
    {
      NSLog(@"Call received");
    }
  };
}
```

But no incoming call UI is shown. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Could it be that CallKit doesn't work in the sim?

Comment: could you help me to where to get CallKit integration to VoIP app with Objective-c, im search from few days, but couldn't found. But, if you have, could you share the link. Thanks!

Comment: CallKit does not work in the iOS Simulator, in case that is where you are testing. Try running on a device instead.

Comment: I'd recommend comparing your app to the sample code app [Speakerbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html) published by Apple to see if there are any pieces missing from your implementation

Comment: @StuartM You are correct. The code works just fine! Please add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper I will post a Gist for you to view later after I've implemented all parts. But if you look at the documentation it's pretty clear even if there aren't any code examples in obj-c.

Comment: When your code in AppDelegate.m then it works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CallKit does not work in the iOS Simulator, so your app will need to be run on a device instead.

Also, I recommend comparing your app to the sample code app [Speakerbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html) published by Apple to see if there are any pieces missing from your implementation.

Comment: @Stuart M, do you have code in objective-c for callkit example?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper Unfortunately no, but all functionality demonstrated in the Swift [Speakerbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app is available from Objective C, just needs to be translated